# C++ workqueue class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, queue

This is a nice workqueue class template to keep the gui fluid, while data is being written into a database or into some file/network...

```
#include <cassert>

#include <condition_variable>

#include <mutex>

#include <thread>

#include <functional>

template <template <typename> class Function = std::function>
class workqueue
{
  using f_t = Function<void()>;

  std::vector<f_t> queue_;

  std::mutex mutex_;

  std::condition_variable cv_;

  std::atomic_bool quit_flag_{false};

  std::thread thread_;

public:
  explicit workqueue() :
    thread_([this]()
      {
        bool qf{};

        while (!qf)
        {
          std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex_)> l(mutex_);

          while (!(qf = quit_flag_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) &&
            queue_.empty())
          {
            cv_.wait(l);
          }

          decltype(queue_) q(std::move(queue_));

          l.unlock();

          for (auto& f: q)
          {
            f();
          }
        }
      }
    )
  {
  }

  ~workqueue()
  {
    assert(!quit_flag_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    quit_flag_.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    cv_.notify_one();

    assert(thread_.joinable());
    thread_.join();
  }

  template <typename F>
  void exec(F&& f)
  {
    {
      std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex_)> l(mutex_);

      queue_.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    cv_.notify_one();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  template <typename F>
  void exec(F&& f)
  {
    {
      std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex_)> l(mutex_);

      queue_.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    cv_.notify_one();
  }
```

This is a bit weird. `emplace_back` allows in-place construction of an object. In this case, it will call the move constructor, copy constructor or a constructor that takes one argument.

If allowing in-place construction of `f_t`s is a necessary feature, it would be better to use a parameter pack and perfect forwarding (so a constructor with any number of arguments can be used).

However, I suspect that isn't the intention at all, and we just want to copy / move a function object. So we should be using `push_back`, not `emplace_back`.

There's also no reason for this to be a template function. We want an `f_t`. The user also has to pass in a compatible `Function` type, and call `exec` with a compatible type so they already have to be aware of exactly what `f_t` is to use the class. So it would be much cleaner to make `f_t` public, take a function object by value (as a sink argument), and move it into place:

```
void exec(f_t f)
{
  ...
    queue_.push_back(std::move(f));
  ...
}
```

This makes the intent instantly obvious, and avoids any complications and downsides involved with universal references.

If performance is a serious concern, then one overload taking an `f_t const&` and one taking an `f_t&&` would be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: usually the argument will be a lambda instance, that will be forwarded (&& or const&) into an `f_t`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should use a templated concurrent queue that's not specific to your work offloading mechanism, instead of implementing one yourself (and not even encapsulating it in its own class). A popular such queue is [Moody Camel's](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue). If you visit that repository's page, you'll see a shorter producer-consumer example (even if it's not exactly what you're implementing).
2. The interface for enqueueing work should support arguments following the function, i.e. a variadic-template method which wraps the arguments in a lambda.

Comment: if you want to store arguments to a function, you can do so in the work lambda itself, i.e. `[a, b, c](){f(a, b, c);}`. I don't really know what you mean. But, yeah, a lock-free queue might be better, but ... these usually come with restrictions and oddities.

Comment: 1. You should offer the users the convenience of not having to wrap up things in their own lambda. 2. The Moody Camel repository also has a blocking (= locking) queue if you'd rather use that.

Comment: lock-free is always good, but I'd rather write my own container, not depend on something external, so... it's just a simple workqueue for your everyday convenience. And allowing for a delayed apply of arguments, ... I don't really need that.

Comment: @user1095108: This is a wrong approach which you should forego. Unless you have an important reason to implement your own container, there cons _far_ outweight the pros. It's _good_ to depend on external code. You depend on things that are , well-tested, well-implemented, and inspire trust. That also makes it easier for you to modularize/componentize and better focus your development effort.

Comment: that's exactly my point, I don't want to debug other people's code, I'd rather debug my own. STL is well-tested, everything else ... not always and lockfree code is notorious for being difficult to implement correctly.

Comment: @user1095108: 1. Again, MoodyCamel has both a locking and a lock-free. 2. Code which  has hundreds of stars on GitHub, is not brand-new, and is actively maintained - is well-tested. You can assume that bugs are in your code. Also, again, separating development of separate components allows for independent debugging and testing.

Comment: we just disagree on the "well-tested" point :)